# ArcGis Rest Vehicle Routing Time Problem

Tags: routing, rest, arcgis-rest-api

I am using the ArcGis vehicle routing rest service.
It works fine until I add in the EarliestStartTime for my route, then it no longer assigns the orders to the routes (delivery windows and breaks also cause the same problem).
Even if I make the EarliestStartTime 0 it still doesn't work, only removing it works.

What am I doing wrong?

```
request=?token=NmsVEs18OZjNkg0jAiUfX-ltrqdqXAQdoZg775KkVpPB6dPPSqm9_N0O2QgR0i8Qnz-AFbi6fGVO60_o7zD2ol43J8nKECoFlZ4QdjndfpAi5JMxtWeot7WUbD5uX-4fFggJWuOgGhiEG7zZt1hmPA..
&default_date=1356998400000
&orders={
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "x": 115.9679,
        "y": -31.78098
      },
      "attributes": {
        "DeliveryQuantities": 1,
        "Name": "5406",
        "ServiceTime": 15
      }
    }
  ]
}
&depots={
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "x": 115.93737,
        "y": -31.90728
      },
      "attributes": {
        "Name": "DBW593",
        "CurbApproach": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
&routes={
  "features": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "Name": "2",
        "StartDepotName": "DBW593",
        "EndDepotName": "DBW593",
        "EarliestStartTime": 1357002000000,
        "ArriveDepartDelay": 5,
        "Capacities": 17,
        "MaxTotalTime": 1095
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.
Turns out if your Route has an EarliestStartTime it must also have a LatestStartTime.